# SignalR user signing in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, signalr, signalr-hub

I've got a SignalR hub (chat app) which is hosted with ASP.NET MVC (or OWIN).

I need **a common cookie authentication**. (Either signing in in the hub itself **or even better in via hosted MVC/OWIN app first**).

The task *sounds pretty trivial*, however, I can not manage that.

There is much info on the web about actually authorizing the access based on already signed in user (contained in request cookies). But there is few info about actually signing the user in and placing the info into cookies (and especially, signing it in in the hosted app, not in the hub itself).

Additionally, some docs with examples [like this](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) just don't work already (probably due to some changes in last versions of SignalR).

*For instance, `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` throws exception and there is even no any `Response` property in `HubCallerContext` available to write the authorization cookies manually.*

I can assume (and even understand) that generally, there might be no sense to write something into the Response, as the SignalR connection is not just a common "postback logic", however, still can not find the way the authentication (signing in) must work.

Answer (score 0):

`SignalR` does not provide you any method of authentication. Instead, it uses the authentication provided by the `Owin` middleware.

If you are using `ASP.NET`, you should just log your user in, the same way as you would with normal ASP app, using `SignInManager`. Then make a `SignalR` connection. `SignalR` will respect that and in your hub context you will get access to logged user, as well as you will be able to use authorization filters.

Remember, that logging in must occur **before** `SignalR` connection is about to start.

And the link you provided is perfectly fine and applies to v2 of `SignalR`.